# FileNotFoundError - if i do not os.chdir to DIRECTORY

Tags: python

I am writing the below code to remove the numerals and special characters if they appear at the starting of a file name. I have a working version of the code however i was trying few things and i noticed something which confused me.

Below is the code that works just fine.

```
import re
import os

DIR = 'C:\Rohit\Study\Python\Python_Programs\Basics\OOP'
os.chdir(DIR)

for file in os.listdir(DIR):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, file)):
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        fname = re.sub(r'(^[0-9. _-]*)(?=[A-Za-z])', "", fname)
        new_name = fname + ext
        os.rename(file, new_name)
```

However if I simply remove the line `os.chdir(DIR)` from above code, I start getting the below error.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '6738903-.   --__..76 test.py'
```

Below is the code that throws the error.

```
DIR_PATH = r'C:\Rohit\Study\Python\Python_Programs\Basics\OOP'

for file in os.listdir(DIR):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, file)):
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        fname = re.sub(r'(^[0-9. _-]*)(?=[A-Za-z])', "", fname)
        new_name = fname + ext
        os.rename(file, new_name)
```

The error is getting generated on the line `os.rename()`.
So can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `file` is not a valid path relative to the current directory (which is not the case if you don't do a `chdir`) you should provide `rename` with the full paths. Otherwise, how do you expect the function to find the file to rename? You did good using `os.path.join` in `isfile` why not doing that with rename?

```
DIR_PATH = r'C:\Rohit\Study\Python\Python_Programs\Basics\OOP'

for file in os.listdir(DIR):
    full_path = os.path.join(DIR, file)
    if os.path.isfile(full_path):
        fname, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        fname = re.sub(r'(^[0-9. _-]*)(?=[A-Za-z])', "", fname)
        new_name = fname + ext
        os.rename(full_path, os.path.join(DIR, new_name))
```

Comment: Thanks alot, my bad i simply didn't look at it, obviously os.rename(file, new_name) would find the file in current path. Sorry my bad.

Comment: @Rohit also not that Anis uses raw prefixes for paths so he doesn't need to uppercase all letters after the backslash to workaround the "strange issue" :)

Comment: also note that chdir is bad practice: what if another module expects another current directory? that will be a chdir battle. Avoid at all costs.